# What deep reinforcement learning algorithm should I use for my problem?

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, deep-rl

So here is a description of my problem:

Essentially, I have a large amount of files filled with code for a number of different tasks. However, lets say these codes are inefficient, and should be edited to be made more efficient. There exists a program to edit this code, and essentially what is does is analyze the code to look for what possible edits can be made, and classifies these edits into 5 classes (Class A, Class B, Class C, Class D, Class E). There is also a program to test the efficiency of this code and yields numeric value quantifying the efficiency. However, choosing some edits benefit the efficiency of a some code better than other edits. For example, a piece of code that has had 5 different edits applied to it (2 of Class A, and 3 of Class C) can be more efficient than the same code that has had 10 edits applied to it (5 of Class A, 5 of Class D). Ideally, the less edits and the higher the efficiency the better.

I want to use deep reinforcement learning to  address this problem.

Here are the goals of my model:

1. Takes the code in a form which it can understand (I have looked into this and stumbled upon code2vec, so I am looking into that)
2. Also can take in the edits that can be applied to the code (which is the action space) and their respective classes.
3. Makes decisions for edits which yield the highest efficiency for the code

I want to train this model on the files filled with the inefficient code. The ultimate goal is to end up with an AI that takes code as an input and makes the best decision of which edits it should apply to the code.

What deep reinforcement learning techniques/algorithms/architecures should I use to approach this problem and how can I go about implementing these in Python? As you can probably tell from this question, I am not very experienced in deep reinforcement learning, but I am willing to learn. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: not specific to the code fixing case, but you might want to google "adaptive operator selection" especially the RL based methods among them. perhaps also google the "learn to improve" paradigms from RL for combinatorial optimization.

Comment: thanks! ill look into that